# How can I classify datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

How can I classify new datasets into classes A and B by using the bellow training data?

```
            1.0  0.9  0.8  0.7  0.6  0.5  0.4  0.3  0.2  0.1  class
Dataset 1   42   13   22   324  270  96   107  93   80   228    A
Dataset 2   45   23   14   596  445  135  153  124  132  331    A
Dataset 3   42   22   16   479  407  130  150  121  128  342    A

Dataset 4   37   63   10   481  397  155  143  159  172  394    B
Dataset 5   46   18   10   387  356  127  118  129  136  359    B
Dataset 6   23   34   9    550  436  147  166  164  208  467    B
```

It will be very ideal if there is a equation that can divide the datasets.

For example if # of 1.0 + # of 0.9 is higher than 55 it is class A.(This might be wrong but something like this)

Comment: First idea that comes to mind: use bagging/boosting to have each of the 10 classifiers vote based on the average.  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18891/bagging-boosting-and-stacking-in-machine-learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you familiar with classification task, it task can be done with almost every classification algorithem like SVM,NN,C4.5,ID3, Random Forest and..

But for formulation Take a look at Logistic Regression: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression. It classify dataset to 2(e.g positive, negative) class

For implenetation, take a look at python scikit linear model, logistic regression: 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html and here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression

```
X = [[...]] #your datasets list of lists(matrix)
y = [...] #your labels list
from sklearn.liner_mode import LogisticRegression
clf = LogisticRegresion()
clf.fit(X,y)
```

This example also can be good: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Naive bayes to predict the class of dataset , by using naive bayes you et get probability for each class, so for illustration in you example you will get say dataset1 probabaility for class A as 70% and class B as 30%

Based on you example you need to use class column as your label column and and 0.1 & 0.9 as you feature columns

Run with your data for ease I took A == 1 & B == 2 for this run
[image]